# selenium web driver unable to click next button due to element is not visible

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate testing on the web form which has three pages and each page has a next button.

Here is HTML:

```
    <div id="Section1Page" class="field fieldgroup bus-form-page nolabel" style="display: block;">
<div class="middleColumn fieldgroup">
   <input class="prev" type="button" value="Previous" style="display: none;">
   <input class="next" type="button" value="Next">
</div>
<div id="Section2Page" class="field fieldgroup bus-form-page nolabel" style="display: none;">
<div class="middleColumn fieldgroup">
<div class="fieldgroup-field first odd">
<div class="fieldgroup-field even">
<div class="fieldgroup-field odd">
<div class="fieldgroup-field even">
<div class="fieldgroup-field odd">
   <div class="fieldgroup-field last even">
      <div class="fieldholder-small">
      </div>
   </div>
   <input class="prev" type="button" value="Previous">
   <input class="next" type="button" value="Next">
</div>
```

I was able to click on the next button on section 1 page by using:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("next")).click();
```

However on the section 2 page, when I execute the click, I get element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.

Please help.

Comment: Add some wait time before you try to click. Probably your page has not been fully loaded.

Comment: yes i already done that by (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Form_Form_AdditionalInformation"))).sendKeys("12345");

Comment: separate you command to separate lines and ensure it actually waits. perhaps do it step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should try to use `JavaScriptExecutor` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);   
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Form_Form_Addition‌​alInformation")));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", el, "12345");
```

**Edited** :- If you have multiple `next` button and you want to find all buttons and `click` to visible button by checking its visibility then try as below :-

```
 List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.className("next"));

 for (WebElement button : buttons) {
         If(button. isDisplayed()) {
                button. click();
          }
  }
```

**Note**:- I'm suggesting you first try to use `visibilityOfElementLocated` instead of `presenceOfElementLocated` and directly could use to `sendKeys` as `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Form_Form_Addition‌​alInformation"))).sendKeys("12345");`, If you are still getting the exception then try to use `JavascriptExecutor` as second option.

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Hi i tried what you suggest and it did input 12345 into the textarea, but when it try to click the next button: driver.findElement(By.className("next")).click, it returned org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with error. I been thinking could it try to click on the next button on the first page instead of current 2nd page? How do i find all the buttons on the whole form and just click through them one by one until one that is visible and clickable? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Tony then use `driver.findElements(By.className("next"))`...it returns `List` if `WebElement`....iterate this list and find visible button by using `isDisplayed()`..

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it works now. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `ExpectedCondition` `visibilityOfElementLocated` instead of `presenceOfElementLocated`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);   
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Form_Form_Addition‌​alInformation"))).sendKeys("12345");
```

Comment: Hi i tried what you suggest and it did input 12345 into the textarea, but when it try to click the next button:  driver.findElement(By.className("next")).click, it returned  org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with error. I been thinking could it try to click on the next button on the first page instead of current 2nd page? How do i find all the buttons on the whole form and just click through them one by one until one that is visible and clickable? Thanks for the help.